# Adding Sum value to active cell VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba, sum

Im trying to add a sum into an active cell but its still not working.

My code:

```
rngCell2.Offset(0, 6).Activate
ActiveCell = ActiveCell + 15
```

When the cell is empty, after execute the cell will get value 15. But when there is already a number f.e 60, it stays 60.

What is wrong in my code, what is the correct code?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
rngCell2.Offset(0, 6).Value = rngCell2.Offset(0, 6).Value + 15
```

This will increase the cell that is 6 columns to the left of `rngCell2` by 15.

If you just need to increase the ActiveCell, try

```
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + 15
```

Comment: "This will increase the cell that is 6 columns to the left of rngCell2 by 15." Thats what it should do, yes. But it doesn't. The activecell.value also doesn't work. very strange because it seems logic

Comment: Oke, my fault your answer worked, i just forgot to add something.

thanks!

Comment: @user2119093: so what was the issue? please accept it as an answer, if it helped!